# How do I enable Azure load balancer diagnostics via the API or RM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have deployed a Load Balancer via an Azure Resource Manager Deployment Template. I have since used the Azure Management Portal to enable diagnostics (alert events and probe health status) on this load balancer to a storage account also defined in my deployment template.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-monitor-log/

How can I specify this load balancer diagnostics configuration up-front in my template? Or via the API?

I have drilled through https://resources.azure.com/ but I cannot find anything representing the diagnostics configuration of the load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the diagnostics settings to turn on diagnostics logs for a specific resource. Please refer to the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template

For load balancer, I used the "non-compute resource template" in my ARM template and it was deployed successfully (the log may show up with long delay though sometimes, but the template should work)

Comment: Thanks. I no longer have a Load Balancer on Azure to verify this but it certainly seems like the approach I'd try first if I did.